# How to make it so a certain role is required in order to execute a command

Tags: discord.net

I would like require a certain role on the user in order for them to use/execute specific commands.

Is there an easy way to do this for individual commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using **Discord.Net 1.0**

```
        var User = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;
        var role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "ROLENAME");

        if (User.Roles.Contains(role))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
```